# How to find the largest ellipsoid under certain constraints?

Tags: optimization, ellipsoids, linear-matrix-inequality

Given a symmetric positive definite matrix $\bf Q$ and a bounded set $\mathcal X$, what is the following maximum?

$$ \max_{{\bf x} \in \mathcal X} {\bf x}' {\bf Q} \, {\bf x} $$

Using a Matlab program and a $2$-dimensional example, I found the maximizing point ${\bf x} \in \mathcal X$. Unfortunately, other $\bf x$'s also maximize the objective and are not in $\mathcal X$. How can I develop an algorithm that solves the problem that for all ${\bf x} \in \mathcal X$ it holds: ${\bf x}' {\bf Q} \, {\bf x} = c$, where $c$ is at its maximum?

Comment: What are the constraints?

Comment: Is $\mathcal X$ convex??

Comment: If you don't know $c$, how is it a constant?

Comment: I still do not understand what you want

Comment: How is this related to LMIs?